# Centos 6 - sudo doesn't recognise pip3.4 when installing mysqlclient for Python 3.4

Tags: python, linux

I am new to `Centos 6` and `Linux`.
 I need to install `Python 3.4` but `Centos 6` came default with `Python 2.6.6`. 

I have installed `Python 3.4` to `/usr/local/lib/Python3.4`. 

However, I am having problems installing `mysqlclient`.

I tried `pip3.4 install mysqlclient`.

This is the error message.

**ERROR**

```
_mysql.c:29:23: error: my_config.h: No such file or directory
_mysql.c:30:19: error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
_mysql.c:31:26: error: mysqld_error.h: No such file or directory
_mysql.c:51:20: error: errmsg.h: No such file or directory
_mysql.c:74: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘MYSQL
_mysql.c:88: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘MYSQL_RES’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_Exception’:
_mysql.c:128: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_errno’
_mysql.c:128: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c:131: error: ‘CR_MAX_ERROR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:131: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
_mysql.c:131: error: for each function it appears in.)
_mysql.c:139: error: ‘CR_COMMANDS_OUT_OF_SYNC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:140: error: ‘ER_DB_CREATE_EXISTS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:141: error: ‘ER_SYNTAX_ERROR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:142: error: ‘ER_PARSE_ERROR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:143: error: ‘ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:144: error: ‘ER_WRONG_DB_NAME’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:145: error: ‘ER_WRONG_TABLE_NAME’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:146: error: ‘ER_FIELD_SPECIFIED_TWICE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:147: error: ‘ER_INVALID_GROUP_FUNC_USE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:148: error: ‘ER_UNSUPPORTED_EXTENSION’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:149: error: ‘ER_TABLE_MUST_HAVE_COLUMNS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:178: error: ‘ER_DUP_ENTRY’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:221: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_error’
_mysql.c:221: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_server_init’:
_mysql.c:325: warning: label ‘finish’ defined but not use
_mysql.c:242: warning: unused variable ‘item’
_mysql.c:241: warning: unused variable ‘groupc'
_mysql.c:241: warning: unused variable ‘i’
...

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/local/bin/python3.4 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__=
'/tmp/pip_build_username/mysqlclient/setup.py';
exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" 
install --record /tmp/pip-s1b9rgku-record/install-record.txt 
--single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 
in /tmp/pip_build_username/mysqlclient
        Storing debug log for failure in /home/username/.pip/pip.log
```

EDIT: Found out what is wrong. Sudo doesn't recognise pip3.4. This link helps: [Installing Python3.4 and the SciPy stack on CentOS](https://edwards.sdsu.edu/research/installing-python3-4-and-the-scipy-stack-on-centos/)

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/pip3.4 install mysqlclient
```

Comment: Hi, could you indicate what **/home/username/.pip/pip.log** log file contains?

Comment: is there anything before the line "error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1" ?

Comment: @scytale - There is a whole long list but this is part of it up till '...' and the rest are a bunch of messages complaining it cannot find member or initialization error.

Comment: Have you installed mysqlclient (rpm) first ? Sounds like it can't find the headers its needs see http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-linux-56-install-mysql-client-only/

Answer (score 6):

Have you installed mysqlclient (rpm) first? Sounds like it can't find the headers its needs

sudo yum install mysql mysql-devel mysql-lib

see http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-linux-56-install-mysql-client-only/

Comment: I tried that and it still complains that it cannot find MySQLdb module when I run my script. Whenever I try to use pip3.4 to install any packages it doesn't work.

Comment: Is there a mysqldb module for python 3 ? For python 3 I use mysql connector (as it doesn't have any dependencies - doesn't need mysql installed).sudo pip install --allow-external mysql-connector-python mysql-connector-python  then import mysql.connector  then the rest of the calls are almost identical  see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/

Comment: Yes it's mysqlclient. The same script works fine in Windows environment. I had to migrate my script to a linux server for testing. If I use pip install mysqlclient - it installs to python 2.6.6 and if I use 'sudo pip3.4 install mysqlclient' -it complains it doesn't recognise pip3.4.

Comment: tried sudo pip3 install ? or same as sudo pip3.4 ? Is pip installed for python3.4 ?

Comment: Yes it should be. I can see pip3.4 in /usr/local/bin. I even added - export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH". I just tried sudo pip3 and it doesn't recognise it at all.

Comment: what do which pip , which pip3 and which pip3.4 give ? also could try sudo yum -f  install python3-pip